# LINQ Where Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

I've the following LINQ to fill a datatable from html `<tr>` tags with the help of HTMLAgilityPack,  each tag has one  attribute and i need to ignore the `innertext` of that tag if the attribute value is "rating-col".

```
nodes.Skip(1)
.Select(
tr => tr.Elements("td").
    Select(td => td.InnerText.
        Where(td.Attributes[0].Value != "rating-col")).
        ToArray()).
        ToList().
        ForEach(row => dt.Rows.Add(row));
```

without the Where clause things work fine, what am i doing wrong inside the `Where` clause?

Comment: If you could, please edit and add your exception or error.

Comment: Not clear if you're trying to just skip one column in every row, or skip certain rows in the table.

Comment: Where(td=> td.Attributes[0].Value != "rating-col"))

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: the OP cannot use `td`. It is an inner `Where` and would redefine `td`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i already skipped the column, but now i need to skip its values

Comment: So the former? You want data from every row, just not that column in the row?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn exactly table on the page looks like col1 col2 col3 i want it col1 col3

Comment: "each tag has one attribute..." this seems like a very brittle test: you are depending on the exact number/position of the attributes to make your logic work. Why not use a specific named attribute, and just target it directly? If this isn't in your control then you should probably look for "rating-col" among all attributes if that's what needs to be done, in case other attributes are ever added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you were missing a lambda and that one of the Selects was out of order. Also, there was no reason for `ToList()` or `ForEach()` here. Your `ToList()` call made things slower and forced you to use more memory. The only reason you need it is to get at the `ForEach()` extension, and that doesn't really save you anything here over a normal `foreach` loop. Plus, while I'm not an expert in that area, I'm given to understand that the `ForEach()` extension is poor functional style, because it almost assumes you're causing side effects (a big functional no-no). Since linq is heavily inspired by the functional programming paradigm, I try to pay attention to such things.

```
foreach (var row in nodes.Skip(1)
     .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")
         .Where(td => td.Attributes[0].Value != "rating-col")
         .Select(td => td.InnerText)
         .ToArray()))
{
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: would that function faster? :D

Comment: It should be. It saves you have from having to loop over your elements twice. Your current code had to loop once to create the list and again  after creating the list to copy those elements to the datatable (plus the extra memory to hold the temporary list). This avoids all that. It only loops once, and only holds on to one row array in memory at a time. It also saves work referencing the InnerText property for columns that won't make the final result.

Answer (score 5):

`Where(td.Attributes[0].Value != "rating-col"))` should have a lambda in it ...such as:

`Where(c => c.Attributes[0].Value != "rating-col"))`

Comment: It also needs to come before the select.

Comment: @user1590636 I hope you understand why.

Comment: @RaymondChen at first i didn't but now i do :D